# How to publish jar to artifactory?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, artifactory

I have to publish a spring boot project to artifactory and need to add some information into manifest. My build.gradle file looks like following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'my-project'
    def gitBranch = java.util.Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv('git.branch')).orElse('no information')
    def gitCommit = java.util.Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv('git.commit')).orElse('no information')
    def gitBuildNumber = java.util.Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv('git.buildno')).orElse('no information')
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at the line `class-path` as follows,

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus, it would be similar for artifactory

Answer (score 0):

Take `dependencies` block out from the `buildScript`, as follows.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}

dependencies {
    ...........
}
```

Comment: If I put do what you say I have an error: ```Could not find method classpath() for arguments [org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.```

Comment: @LukasKörfer can you give some example, please?

Answer (score 0):

The two blocks `repositories` and `dependencies` can be defined as top-level blocks as well as under the `buildscript` block. The top-level blocks are used to define production dependencies for your code and how to resolve them. The blocks in the `buildscript` block are used to define plugin dependencies and how to resolve them:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // define how to resolve plugin dependencies
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // define plugin dependencies
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE"
    }
}

repositories {
    // define how to resolve production dependencies
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // define production dependencies
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this example not working for me. I have got the same error.